# Reordering data in ggplot creates mismatch between data and bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data based off responses to a survey:

```
1 ABSENCE OF BULLYING         0.665
2 SENSE OF SAFETY         0.614
3 FAIRNESS OF DISCIPLINE        0.677
4 FEELINGS OF EMOTIONAL SAFETY         0.585
5 PERCEPTION OF EQUITABLE TREATMENT         0.691
6 COMFORT OF PHYSICAL ENVIRONMENT         0.509
```

I want to create a bar graph graph with this data and to cut down the excess text in the label, so I did the following:

```
fig4 = read_excel(data)

order = c("bullying", "safety", "discipline", "emotional", "equity", "environment")

fig4$domain = as.factor(order)

levels(fig4$domain) = order

ggplot(fig4, aes(x = reorder(domain, desc(domain)), y = pct_responses)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", width=0.5, fill="#3bbae0") +
  vertical_theme +
  labs(y = "% of Affirmative Responses", x = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,1),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,0.2),
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste0(round(pct_responses*100),"%")), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size=scale_factor * 6, hjust=-0.25)
```

However, this created a graph where the bars don't match with the right axis label. Rows 2, 3, and 6 have the wrong numbers.

[image]

I fixed the problem by using this code instead:

```
fig4$domain = c("bullying", "safety", "discipline", "emotional", "equity", "environment")
fig4$domain = factor(fig4$domain, levels = fig4$domain)
```

This solved the issue. However, I'm not sure why the first way I did it messed up my graph. Can someone please explain what happened?

Comment: When using `fig4$domain = as.factor(order)` the levels are ordered alphabetically. `levels(fig4$domain) = order` then overwrites the levels (in the new ordering) with the levels in `order` (in the old ordering). Assigning levels like that is dangerous, you should use the `levels` and `labels` arguments in `factor`. So `fig4$domain <- factor(fig4$domain, unique(fig4$domain), order)`.

Comment: I can see now that while the "x" axis was re-ordered in the way I wanted it to be ordered, the "y" axis remained in the old, alphabetical order. So levels() reordered fig4$domain but it did not reorder fig4$pct_responses. But then why does it work when I do it the other way?